# Very strange behaviour with one of my questions

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I have this [Terminal Tips & Tricks for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/52483/terminal-tips-and-tricks-for-mac-os-x) question since last October. I have also since gotten 3 Gold badges off of it. Sure I like them, but it seems iffy that the question would have this much activity *now*, so long after I asked it.

I am getting almost daily updates of people with 1 rep posting answers. The question itself has 75k views. That's a lot of views!

Can someone check and make sure that this is legit? I.e., that the users are real?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was linked to on [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2010/07/25/terminal-tips) a few days ago, so it was probably passed around on Twitter and Hacker News as well.  I'd say it's just a legitimate spike in traffic to the post.

Comment: See, I should get some sort of alert when stuff gets linked from DF.

Comment: It actually hit Hacker News three weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it was linked from a very popular blog or website, such as slashdot.

This explains the spike of interest and the 1 rep users.

Comment: Indeed, a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=linkto%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Fquestions%2F52483%2Fterminal-tips-and-tricks-for-mac-os-x) for links to the post returns 95 results.